Why is the title of the poem "The Road Not Taken" Appropriate?
I have read the poem, "The Road Not Taken" recently.
You can read this here.
The source of my confusion is: Why did Robert Frost choose to name his poem that way?
Read this Guardian Article by Mathew Hollis, which goes over the history of the friendship of Edward Thomas and Robert Frost.
In a way, the poem can be interpreted as a warning to the overthinkers, who spend most of their time trying to choose between two paths. In the end, one will also sigh, and think about the other.
Well, some may argue that, since there are two roads, and the other road is not travelled by, as much, hence the title is the way it is.
But in the second stanza, it is clearly written:

Though as for that the passing there
Had worn them really about the same.

Both of the roads are equally travelled by. The 'sigh' mentioned in the last paragraph is a mock sigh.
Also, at the last paragraph, the emotional meaning travels two trajectories, both that can't be true at the same time. A sigh can be of content or disappointment. The difference could be positive or negative.
Our original decision may seem good, but people change, and the world too changes. With this continuous change, it isn't impossible to imagine that the decision which was originally good, may turn out to be rubbish. We know our reasons don't hold much weight, but we we still choose randomly. At the end, we are left rationalizing our choice or overstating their significance.
This supports the historical themes of the poem.
Then what does it mean for the title to be written 'The Road Not Taken'?
Is one of the roads genuinely less travelled by, or is there a difference between 'travelled' and 'taken'?

He chose the road that looked as if fewer people had used it, although on second thoughts there probably wasn't much difference between them (see this question).

That is what I also think.
But, then, the entire poem, is based on that first incorrect perception. I find it hard to believe.

No, because he could only take one road, so there had to be one he didn't take!

Oh! Thank you! A big piece of the puzzle!
But why do you think, Robert Frost concentrated on this part of the poem, and not any other? He had initially picked the title as "Two roads", and then changed it into "The Road Not Taken".
Source is that guardian article by Mathew Hollis where he writes:

But the problem was not endless as Thomas thought, for a poem of Frost's had  arrived by post that would dramatically force Thomas's hand: a poem called "Two Roads", soon to be rechristened "The Road Not Taken".


You are misinterpreting the title. It refers specifically to the narrator, not the general public. Travellers in general have taken both the roads. But the narrator can only take one. It appears to be a trivial decision at the time, and there's nothing much to recommend one over the other. He takes the one that appears less traveled by, which is a clue to his psychology--he's a contrarian, someone who doesn't like to follow the crowd.
The last line, as taken in conversation with the title, tells us that he's using this minor, forgettable incident as a metaphor for a life in which he's consistently chosen to go against the crowd, and that he has wonders about whether that was the right decision or not--questions about what it would have been like to stick with the masses instead.
